# How to remove core taxonomy rss feeds

Tags: taxonomy-terms, theming, feeds

I'm creating my own custom taxonomy rss feeds and have added those sucessfully to the head on term pages. Now, however, I need to remove the core taxonomy feed from those pages (currently it shows 2 feeds: the custom feed and the core feed).

Many people have suggested simply using the taxonomy view which overrides the core term and feed displays, but for complex reasons I can't use this solution.

I need to programmatically remove the feed from the head.

The original feed in the page head looks like this:

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="RSS - termname" href="/taxonomy/term/2764/0/feed">
```

My best attempt to remove this is done in template.php and shown below, but it doesn't work:

```
mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  //target taxonomy term pages
  if(arg(0) == 'taxonomy' && arg(1) == 'term' && is_numeric($arg2)) {
    $variables['head'] = preg_replace('/<link rel="alternate" type="application\/rss\+xml" title=".*?" href=".*?">/', '', $variables['head']);
  }
}
```

I probably need to get even more specific on the 'href' portion as well, so it only removes the term feed...but I haven't gotten that far yet.

I also tried adding `$variables['head'] = drupal_get_html_head();` at the end just to reload the head, in case it was necessary, and that doesn't help.

How can I programmatically remove this feed?

Comment: SE thread about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597171/drupal-remove-rss

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the [RSS Permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/rss_permissions) module? Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> Set role-based permission settings for blog, taxonomy, aggregator, and main site's RSS feeds. This module does not disable RSS feeds altogether: RSS feeds created through the Views module and others not listed here do not have associated permissions.
>
> RSS permissions module lets you disable some or all RSS feeds based on different user roles, and was created as a stopgap solution for [#28337: Add permissions to disable RSS feeds](https://www.drupal.org/node/28337).
>
> This module adds role-based permission settings to blog, taxonomy, aggregator, and main site's RSS feeds.

Comment: This isn't a bad solution but I'd rather do it programatically...installing a module for this one purpose on a site that already has a ton of modules isn't ideal.  I'll consider this a 'last resort'.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using D7 hook_html_head_alter is your friend.

something like

```
function my_html_head_alter(&$head_elements) {
  foreach ($head_elements as $key => $element) {
    if (isset($element['#attributes']['type']) && $element['#attributes']['type'] == 'application/rss+xml') {
      unset($head_elements[$key]);
    }
  }
}
```

Otherwise your attempt seems to be the best solution. Perhaps try ungreedy regex?

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application\/rss\+xml" title="[^"]*?" href="[^"]*?">
```

Comment: Unfortunately it's D6 :(

Comment: Then you could use hook_menu_alter as RSS Permissions does and disable `$items['taxonomy/term/%']` (http://drupalcode.org/project/rss_permissions.git/blob/refs/heads/6.x-1.x:/rss_permissions.module)

Comment: Yeah I started to reverse engineer what that module is doing and it may be a good solution.  It gets weird because the callbacks are the same for both the term and feed pages.